# Enter numbers and print them in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to make a box for entering a number by the user, and doing simple arithmetic operations on it, and printing the result through a table, consisting of fixed numbers and variables that are the result of the arithmetic operations on it. I made the variables to receive the value and make the calculations, and I prepared a matrix containing the fixed numbers with the variables being put in their places.

```js
function generate_table() {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var x = document.getElementById("num").Value
  var y = x - 20;
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    var t1 = [8, (y - 1), 3, 10]
    var t2 = [11, 2, (y + 2), 5]
    var t3 = [y, 7, 9, 4]
    var t4 = [1, 12, 6, (y + 1)]


    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    var td3 = document.createElement('td');
    var td4 = document.createElement('td');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode(t1[i]);
    var text2 = document.createTextNode(t2[i]);
    var text3 = document.createTextNode(t3[i]);
    var text4 = document.createTextNode(t4[i]);

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    td3.appendChild(text3);
    td4.appendChild(text4);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    tr.appendChild(td3);
    tr.appendChild(td4);

    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num">
<input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick="generate_table()">
```

The problem is that the table comes out without the variable values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1lKn.png)

I tried to add a form between the button and the input and the result is the same.

And I want to add a condition if the entry is not entered, it is not printed, and after the entry, the modification is prohibited.

Comment: Input elements don't have a `.Value` property, it's `.value`

Comment: also input is always a String so maybe you need to convert with **parseInt()** or **parseFloat()** like **parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value)**

Comment: Your code here is incomplete (there's a missing end bracket `}`). Beyond that, and the misspelling of `value`, you need to append the `table` you created to the document somewhere, like `document.body.appendChild(table);`.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question. Your two additional questions, one regarding requiring entry, and the other disallowing reentry, can be answered separately. Please do search for preexisting questions about those behaviors though, as I'm pretty sure they have been asked before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, make sure that you change your **.Value** to **.value** like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("num").value;
```

Also, since the value you're getting from the input box is of type `string` you have to parse it into a number!

Here are some examples how you can do that:

```
// During the variable declaration:
var x = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
// Or
var x = +document.getElementById("num").value;
// Or
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value;
```

In my own opinion the best way is to use the `Number` object an its `parseInt` method, that makes it way more readable than using a simple `+` character!

Have a good day!

Comment: The `x` value will be coerced to a number by the subtraction of 20, so `y` will be a number, which is the only thing used in the remainder of the code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will solve the issue, but at first glance there are a couple of things wrong with this line:

```
var x = document.getElementById("num").Value
```

First of all, .value should be all lowercase. Then, what you're getting from the input box is actually a String that needs to be converted to a Number. You can do that by adding a plus sign at the beginning. Here's how that line should look like:

```
var x = +document.getElementById("num").value;
```

Comment: The `x` value will be coerced to a number by the subtraction of 20, so `y` will be a number, which is the only thing used in the remainder of the code.

Comment: Still is a good practice to convert it to a number. The variable could be used later and generate issues as if it's used in "x + x". It's not recommended to rely on type coercion.